# Update app in background

Tags: ios, background, today-extension

I want to create my own train app for learning.

My opinions:
- some dates and times (for example, Monday, 20 May 12:12 am train is coming).
So I will have many data and I will save it with Core Data.

Also I will create a today extension which will show something like: "next train comes in 7 minutes".

My question is: How can I make the background updates?
The app must check every X minutes and look if some train is coming by date/time.

What's the best way to do that? Is it possible? Or will the iOS core terminate my app in background?

What's with the battery remainig time?

Comment: May be you are looking for CLLocation?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks i will read the documentation,
but i think i must have an Server that sends a notification to the App.
Everything Timer or something like that will terminate by iOS core